# Print all numbers from -100 to 100 which contain a given digit

Tags: code-golf

Provided a digit between 0 and 9 (inclusive), your function/subroutine should print all numbers between -100 and 100 (inclusive) that contain the given digit.

For example:

```
Input: 9
Output: -99 -98 -97 -96 -95 -94 -93 -92 -91 -90 -89 -79 -69 -59 -49 -39 -29 -19 -9 9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

**Rules:**

- You cannot use strings (in whatever way they are represented in your chosen language) or char arrays. (Except to print the answer to the console.)
- You cannot use arrays.

**Scoring:**

Score = length of subroutine/function (whitespace will not be counted)

The answer with the lowest score wins.

Whitespace will NOT be counted. Please format your code properly!

Some answers are using regular expressions, which may violate the no strings rule, as pointed out by some members. These answers will not be accepted.

Please test your code with `0` before posting.

Comment: The given output is either wrong or unclear. Where are -98 ... -91 and 91 ... 98?

Comment: Define "use" and "loop".

Comment: What @PeterTaylor said. I could just use labels and gotos in C.

Comment: Removed the no loops rule.

Comment: Does the order of the output matter? Is `9,-9,19,-19,...` acceptable?

Comment: @Gaffi The order does matter.

Comment: A Whitespace answer will score 0. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Is a list an array?

Comment: @DavidCarraher Functionally, they are both a collection of quantities, so I would consider a list a type of array (though they actually aren't).

Comment: If you add the word 'only' after your post heading...It will be a nice challenge !

Comment: Is use of regex allowed?  Working with regex means working with strings. Similarly working with lists/collections (and similar structures) is same as working with arrays. The answer from @wallywest here uses regex.  This is the thing that I don't like about questions when they try to prohibit from using string and/or arrays.  People find alternate ways of using them.  And if any answer really does implement correctly, it does not get as many votes as it should just because it looks complicated.

Comment: @microbian I thought the same, but due to my lack of knowledge in JavaScript, I did not want to point it out and find out I was wrong. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Also why from -100 to +100.  Numbers found on negative side are same as in the positive side.  So if you find 19 for 9, you can automatically add -19 in output.

Comment: @microbian, an interesting case is 0. we dont want -0 as an answer.

Comment: "Whitespace will NOT be counted. Please format your code properly!" isn't a great way of doing this, since whitespace in different languages have different significance. More often, it's just "post an ungolfed/readable version too".

Comment: @ace I created an answer in whitespace (needed 4 hours of hard work with this). i think that it scores zero, right?

Comment: @Victor Sorry, I'm new here. Didn't know that. It'd be great to see your whitespace answer, as a clever way through the rules, and of course, the winning answer.

Comment: The "EDIT" monikers in your question are unnecessary.  Every question comes with a detailed edit history which anyone can review; you can access the edit history for this question here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/22975/revisions

Comment: Maybe for the future a better way to exclude whitespace from the count without allowing "cheating" would be "insignificant whitespace will not be counted".

Comment: What does "no strings" mean exactly? e.g. would having a Python expression `x in str(i)` count as using a string?

Comment: @Claudiu Yes, it does.

Comment: How can we do it without strings? In many languages, printing functions only accept strings as arguments.

Comment: @JanDvorak Of course, you are allowed to use strings to print the answer to the console. But not for any other purpose.

Comment: @duci9y I may suggest that next time you present a question, that you flesh it out in the Sandbox. You mention no strings initially, without mentioning the ban on string functions or regexp. Multiple edits (as I have found out in the past) can piss off other coders...)

Comment: not to mention it never specifically says _only_ the numbers containing those characters or how many times they could be printed

Comment: @technosaurus You could go on and on. You'd argue that I did not specify if the printed numbers should in roman numerals or arabic, whether they should be printed to a printed or to the console, etc.

Comment: Downvote for the arbitrary restriction of not allowing arrays. Makes the challenge so much less fun.

Comment: How do Array Programming Languages (APLs) participate? In APL, data is always an array.

Comment: @Nᴮᶻ Of course, reasonable exceptions apply. 

Comment: I am going to close this question as unclear.  Since this challenge was posted the site has leaned much more in favor of requiring concrete observable criteria independent of language features.  Forbidding strings is just not clear by modern standards.  This will not impact anyone's reputation and is not a punishment of any form.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

### Whitespace, 834 characters (0 if you subtract whitespaces)

Used [this interpreter](http://ws2js.luilak.net/interpreter.html) to test it.

This took me some 4 hour of hard work and horrible debugging to create. But it is done!

**EDIT**: Selectable text provided with HTML tricks. If you copy and paste it from here to some other place, please check if you got exactly `[space][tab][linefeed][linefeed][linefeed]` at the end with 100 or 101 lines (depending if your editor counts or not a new line if the last one ends with a linefeed).

In the case that you can't use it this way, considering space as `S`, linefeed as `L` and tab as `T`, and breaking lines after the `L`'s, here it is:

```
SSSTSSSSTSL
SSSTSSSSTSL
TL
TSSSSTSSSSTSL
TTTSSSTTSSSSL
TSSTTTSSSSTSSSSTTL
SSTTTSSSTTL
TTSSSSTSSSSSTL
SSSL
TTSSSSTSSSSTSL
TTTL
TSSTSSTSTTL
SSSTSSSSTSL
TTTSSSTL
TSSTL
TSSTSSTSTTL
L
SSSTSSSTSSL
SSSTSSSSTTL
TTTSL
SSSSTTSSTSSL
TSSTL
TSSTSSSTSTL
SL
SSSTTL
TSSL
L
TTSTSSSTTTL
SSTTL
TSSL
L
SSSTSSSTTTL
SL
SSSSTSSSSTSL
TTTL
TSSTSSTSSSL
SSSTSTSL
TSTSSSSTSSSSTSL
TTTTSSTL
TSSTSSTSSTL
L
SSSTSSTSSSL
SSSTSTSL
TSTTSSSTSSSSTSL
TTTTSSTL
TSSTSSTSSTL
L
SL
STSSTSTSL
L
SSSTSSTSSTL
SSSTSSSSSTL
TTTL
TSSTSSSTTSL
SSSTSSSSSL
TL
SSL
SSSTSSSTTSL
SSSTSSSSSTL
SSSTL
TTSSSSTSSSSTTL
TTTTL
STL
SSSTSSTSTSL
SSSTSSSSTTL
SSSTSSSSTTL
TTTSSSTL
TSSSTTSL
SL
STSSSTSSL
L
SSSTSSSTSTL
SSSTSSSSTSL
TTTL
TSSTSSTTSSL
SSSTSSSSTSL
TTTSSSTL
TSSTL
TSSTSSTTSSL
L
L
L
L
SSSTSSTSTTL
SSTTTSSTSSL
TL
STSSSTSSSSSL
TL
SSL
SL
STSSSTSSL
L
SSSTSSTTSSL
SSSTSSSSSL
TL
SSSSSTTSSTSSL
TL
STL
L
L
```

Comment: +1 exploiting "0 if you subtract whitespaces"

Comment: Haha, I learnt a lesson. :P

Comment: I never understood this language. Everything seems highly ambiguous to me. How do you know when a number finishes, and the next command begins?

Comment: @Cruncher The language is [well defined and entirely unambiguous](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php). For your particular question: a number is a series of spaces and tabs, representing the number in binary (space = 0, tab = 1, big-endian binary format) and is terminated by a newline. So you know a number finishes when you reach a newline.

Comment: I learnt Whitespace today. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23216/17886

Comment: @TimS. I think it's worth noting that I didn't actually claim that the language was ambiguous. I assumed it to be well-defined, just that in the few minutes I've spent reading on it a few times, it **appeared** ambiguous to me

Comment: I interpret "Whitespace will NOT be counted." to mean this answer is invalid. ;) +1

Comment: It would be better if you provide the `base64` encoding of the code.

Comment: At the end of this answer I added a whitespace precompiler making it easier to do WS programming: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20328/c-code-indenter/20773#20773

Comment: Should have won if a Popularity Contest :D

Comment: @Daniel It actually wins. :)

Comment: whitespaces is the only character recognize by this language, thus it must be included :p . +1 btw. I learn new language today. yay

Comment: "Whitespace will not be counted" That means this answer (written in whitespace) will be not counted, rendering this invalid :P

Answer (score 24):

**Bash+utils - 20**

```
seq -100 100|grep 9
```

Or 21 bytes if in a script

```
seq -100 100|grep $1
```

To run the script:

```
sh myscript 9
```

Comment: `grep` isn't `bash` or `sh`.  It's another utility!

Comment: i have to agree, it is not pure shell/bash :)

Comment: *Sees question.* *Makes answer in mind.* *Sees exact same answer already posted.* Darn! +1

Comment: I think this is using strings.

Comment: @DavidConrad If you look at it that way, everything uses strings. The program source is a string. The terminal uses strings. Etc.

Comment: The point is (to me), that it uses substrings of the base-10 number, rather than arithmetic, to determine whether to include it. Seems like skirting the rule to me, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: All variables are strings in Bash unless typeset (see [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Chapter 4](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html) and [Chapter 9](http://www.museum.state.il.us/ismdepts/library/linuxguides/abs-guide/declareref.html) ), but even if you typeset your input is still cast back to string when passed to `seq`. This answer uses strings and as such is invalid.

Comment: Should I delete the answer?

Comment: If you use busybox instead of bash, `grep` and `seq` are a kind of builtins. `busybox`'s `seq` doesn't like negative numbers as 1st argument, so it needs to count backwards. `seq 100 -1 -100 | grep 9` does the trick on my OpenWrt routers using `busybox`.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript 133 - 1 = 132

Surely there couldn't possibly be anything wrong with this version now...?

```
for(k=prompt(),c=console,j=-100;100>=j;j++)if(i=j,0==j&j==k)c.log(0);else for(;i;)if(h=i%10,h=0>h?-h:h,i=i/10|0,h==k){c.log(j);break}
```

---

```
PROMPT: 2
CONSOLE.LOG:
-92
-82
-72
-62
-52
-42
-32
-29
-28
-27
-26
-25
-24
-23
-22
-21
-20
-12
-2
 2
 12
 20
 21
 22
 23
 24
 25
 26
 27
 28
 29
 32
 42
 52
 62
 72
 82
 92

CONTROL, using zero
PROMPT: 0
CONSOLE.LOG:
    -100
    -90
    -80
    -70
    -60
    -50
    -40
    -30
    -20
    -10
      0
     10
     20
     30
     40
     50
     60
     70
     80
     90
    100
```

Comment: Even a bit shorter: `for(i=-100,r=prompt();101>i;i++)(i+'').match(r)&&console.log(i)`.

Comment: I like this answer (+1), but doesn't it implicitly use strings?

Comment: It uses strings because it uses regex.

Comment: this does use implicit string conversion

Comment: Actually chaps, no it doesn't... `alert(RegExp(9).test(99))` which is based on numbers only, also returns `true` due to JavaScript's loosely based typing system. The functions work with the numbers as though they are strings but are still numbers...

If you change the code to read `r=RegExp(x=+prompt());for(i=-100;101>i;i++)r.test(i)&&console.log(i);console.log(typeof(x));console.log(typeof(i))` and executed it, the final typeof response would show `x` and `i` as being numbers... Ergo, I'm not using strings...

Comment: @VoronoiPotato A string operator that is using a number as an argument... JavaScript does type conversion on the fly, who am I to tell JavaScript how and when to do it?

Comment: This answer was given before the edit stating no regExp... Sorry about that... I've since edited it...

Comment: @VoronoiPotato printing is also a string op. But we are obviously required to do that.

Comment: @Claudiu I'm converting numbers not strings...

Comment: @WallyWest: You're using strings. `(1).toString()` converts `1` into a `Number`, and then calls its `toString` method, which returns a **string**, and then you call `.search` on that string which converts it to a `String` object and calls the .`search` method of the `String` object. Just because the string is only a temporary variable doesn't mean you aren't using strings.

Comment: @Claudiu Are you serious? You're complaining because I'm chaining string conversion methods onto a number to generate a string, which is perfectly valid, as opposed to using a direct string. "I'm not allowed to use strings", but the rules do not say that I cannot use string conversion methods, including RegExp. The whole program is a string. I have to use `console.log` which outputs (surprise surprise) in the form of a string... Do you plan on chastising me on that too? How about you provide a solution which abides by your interpretation of the rules, and then perhaps we'll stand up & listen.

Comment: @WallyWest: Chill yo. I asked the OP what he meant by "no strings", but I thought he meant you should use number functions (like modulo and division) to check for inclusion, instead of converting to a string and using string contain/search functions.

Comment: @WallyWest: Ah see now the OP [has spoken](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22975/print-all-numbers-from-100-to-100-which-contain-a-given-digit?noredirect=1#comment48411_22975). converting to a string *does* count as using a string - this answer is invalid unfortunately!

Comment: @Claudiu Indeed, invalid answer.

Comment: @duci9y You present me with a conundrum... Hopefully, my NEW answer is more suitable... No arrays, no strings, no string functions or methods, save for the output method...

Answer (score 8):

## GolfScript [24 bytes]

```
`:x;201,{100-}%{`x?-1>},
```

**Description:**

```
`:x;             - save input value to variable 'x' and remove from the stack
201,{100-}%      - create range from -100 to 100
{`x?-1>},        - filter the range by "index-of" condition
```

**DEMO:** http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MwoKYDp4OzIwMSx7MTAwLX0le2B4Py0xPn0sYA%3D%3D

Comment: this uses strings, though

Comment: It also uses arrays: 201, creates an array containing 0 to 200.

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby: 92 characters

```ruby
s=gets.to_i
$><<(-100..100).select{|n|a=n.abs;loop{break""if a%10==s;break if 0==a/=10}}*" "
```

Readable version:

```ruby
searchfor = gets.to_i
$><< (-100..100).select { |number|
  absnumber = number.abs
  loop {
    break "" if absnumber % 10 ==s
    break if 0 == absnumber /= 10
  }
} * " "
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ ruby -e 's=gets.to_i;$><<(-100..100).select{|n|a=n.abs;loop{break""if a%10==s;break if 0==a/=10}}*" "' <<< 9
-99 -98 -97 -96 -95 -94 -93 -92 -91 -90 -89 -79 -69 -59 -49 -39 -29 -19 -9 9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

Test run:

```
bash-4.2$ for i in {0..9}; do diff -w <(ruby -e 's=gets.to_i;$><<(-100..100).select{|n|a=n.abs;loop{break""if a%10==s;break if 0==a/=10}}*" "' <<< $i) <(seq -100 100|grep $i|tr \\n \ ) > /dev/null; echo "$i : $?"; done
0 : 0
1 : 0
2 : 0
3 : 0
4 : 0
5 : 0
6 : 0
7 : 0
8 : 0
9 : 0
```

Comment: Fails the `0` test.

Comment: Oops. You're right, @duci9y. Corrected.

Answer (score 6):

### bash <del>55</del> 49 characters:

(not counting whitespace around `&&`)

```
for i in {-100..100}
do
  [[ $i =~ $1 ]] && echo $i
done
```

Executing it by saying:

```
bash filename 9
```

would produce:

```
-99
-98
-97
-96
-95
-94
-93
-92
-91
-90
-89
-79
-69
-59
-49
-39
-29
-19
-9
9
19
29
39
49
59
69
79
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
```

Comment: You can replace " && " with "&&" for two extra points.  Also I count one less char if I drop the trailing newline.

Comment: Scratch that - I just saw the new rule: *"EDIT: Whitespace will NOT be counted. Please format your code properly!"*.  So I guess you just get to count all non-whitespace characters?

Comment: Then you can convert the `;`s to newlines, and save 2 points.

Answer (score 6):

## K - 45 char

Not winning any awards, but K golfing is underrepresented. K doesn't get any prettier with proper spacing, so I'll just leave this as is, because K gets very picky about which whitespace is important and which isn't.

```
{|a@&x _in'@[10_vs'_ _abs a:100-!201;100;0,]}
```

Explained:

- `a:100-!201` - Make a list from 0 to 200 inclusive, then subtract it from 100. Now we have the numbers from -100 to 100 inclusive, but backwards from the question's specs. We can always fix that later, so for now we'll just assign this to `a`.
- `_ _abs` - Take the floor of the absolute value of these numbers, because for whatever reason K thinks that `_abs` should give floating point results. Thankfully, flooring them turns them back into integers.
- `10_vs'` - Expand each (`'`) integer as a base 10 number (`_vs` stands for "vector from scalar"). Note that we did not have to use the Each operator `'` on the functions above because they operate on atoms.
- `@[...;100;0,]` - Amend the item in our list at index 100 (an empty list, which is the result of expanding 0 into base 10) by the function `0,`, which prepends a zero to the front. Without this correction, this function will fail on the input 0.
- `&x in'` - Now, return the indices (`&`) where `x` is a digit in (`_in`) each (`'`) of the expansions we so carefully constructed above.
- `|a@` - Finally, use these indices to index `a`, and reverse the list into the right order.

Usage is obvious, though good luck getting your hands on a K interpreter. (There's an open source implementation at [on Github](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona) that you can compile.)

```
  {|a@&x _in'@[10_vs'_ _abs a:100-!201;100;0,]} 0
-100 -90 -80 -70 -60 -50 -40 -30 -20 -10 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
  {|a@&x _in'@[10_vs'_ _abs a:100-!201;100;0,]} 5
-95 -85 -75 -65 -59 -58 -57 -56 -55 -54 -53 -52 -51 -50 -45 -35 -25 -15 -5 5 15 25 35 45 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 65 75 85 95
```

Comment: I wonder if languages like K have any productive uses outside of scenarios like this question. Do they?

Comment: @duci9y Actually, [K in particular](http://www.kx.com/) has found itself a niche market on Wall Street handling high-speed, high-volume transactions, using its native database software KDB. [The close relative J](http://jsoftware.com/) also finds use, though more in corporate and academic contexts.

Comment: That's great! I was of the belief that esoteric languages are just for fun. Good to see that's not the case.

Comment: Doesn't the description say "You cannot use arrays"?

Answer (score 4):

## C - <strike>104</strike> <strike>107</strike> 114 characters - 0 = <strike>104</strike> <strike>107</strike> 114

```c
a,b;main(i){i=getchar()-48;for(a=-100;a<101;a++){for(b=a;a&&abs(a%10)!=i;a/=10);if(a|!i&!b)printf("%i ",b);a=b;}}
```

Ungolfed:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int a, b;

int main(int i) {
    i = getchar() - '0';
    for( a = -100 ; a < 101 ; a++ ) {
        for( b = a ; a && abs(a % 10) != i ; a /= 10 );
        if( a | !i & !b )
            printf("%i ", b);
        a = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Could you also post an ungolfed version with proper whitespace please?

Comment: @duci9y Added it.

Comment: Won't this output the results out of order? (Spec has been updated to state that order matters.)

Comment: @Gaffi Well then. I shall edit the code.

Comment: Fails to notice that `0` contains `0`.

Comment: I think the condition of the `if`-clause should be `a | !i & !b`

Comment: @konjac true, and is so in my ungolfed file. I'm wondering why it wasn't pasted correctly...

Answer (score 4):

## PHP 67 bytes:

```php
for($i=-100;$i<101;++$i)if(strpos($i,$_GET[n])!==!1)echo$i,PHP_EOL;
```

Yes, there is a 'strpos' call, but I'm using only numbers!

Here is a 'ungolfed' version:

```php
for($i=-100;$i<101;++$i)
{
    if(strpos($i,$_GET[n])!==false)
    {
        echo $i,PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

For this to work, you can test it here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Just remember to add `$_GET[n]='<number>';` to the beginning of the code.

Or, on a lamp or xampp server, you can create a page and then access it on the browser, with the parameter `?n=<number>` after the filename.

Comment: This looks like implicit string conversion, violating the no strings rule.

Comment: Not my fault. I didn't made the language. I used what I have. Besides, the conversion is made internally. There is nothing in the code dealing with strings (except the output).

Comment: The way I read the rule, you have to deal with the numbers arithmetically. Treating them as strings, whether by you or by the language or library, is off limits. But almost everyone else is skirting the rule in a similar way.

Comment: Well, everyone wants to get it done the smallest way. And the smallest is treating the numbers as strings (internally without implicit conversion to string in the code).

Answer (score 4):

My first attempt here, so maybe I am doing some things wrong, please excuse that ;)
So, I wasn't sure if I had to add the whole class or just the logic within.

## Java  - 199 characters

```
intx=System.in.read()-48;for(inti=-100;i<101;i++){if((i<10&&i==-x)||(i>-10&&i==x)||(i<-9&&((i/100==x&&i<-99)||i%10==-x||i/10==-x))||(i>9&&((i/100==x&&i>99)||i%10==x||i/10==x)))System.out.println(i);}
```

Here a more readable form:

```
int x = System.in.read() - 48;
for(int i = -100; i < 101; i++) {

    if((i < 10 && i == -x) || (i > -10 && i == x)
        || (i < -9 && ((i / 100 == x && i < -99 ) || i % 10 == -x || i / 10 == -x))
        || (i > 9 && ((i / 100 == x && i > 99) || i % 10 == x || i / 10 == x)))

        System.out.println(i);

}
```

I guess the basic idea was not that bad, but needed too much exceptions, to finally work out for all cases... :/

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work with `0` :(

Comment: Aw, sure, last addition I made messed that up.
Updated Code, so I'm down to 199 now.
Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Didn't realize that one :D  
Too much coding in native language in the past days I guess ;)

Comment: You removed every single space in your compacted version... wouldn't that cause an error? Example: Your first 4 characters: `intx`... shouldn't it be: `int x`?

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica 28

Sorry, I just couldn't resist.

:)

The instructions are:
"Provided a digit between 0 and 9 (inclusive), your function/subroutine should print all numbers between -100 and 100 (inclusive) that contain the given digit."

---

The following prints all such numbers in order.

```
f@n_ :=Print/@Range[-100,100]
```

As a special bonus, it prints those numbers in the same range that do not contain the given digit.  :)

Comment: But this do not use n as a filter

Comment: @Marta, Yes, I subverted the intent of the puzzle (which is why I said "Sorry"), while technically providing an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

### R 87 <strike>93</strike>

Here's an improvement:

```
a=scan();r=-100:100;s=abs(r);r[(!a&!r%%10)|a&(a==s%%10|a==floor(s/10)|a==floor(s/100))]
```

(Potentially) More readable, with notes:

```
a=scan() # take user input of selected digit
r=-100:100 # define our scanning range
s=abs(r) # copy the range as the absolute value for proper floor() calculation
#r[<criteria>] is functionally the same as subset(r,<criteria>)
r[ # when any of the criteria below are met, use that value from the range
    (!a & !r%%10) # case when input is 0, !a is evaluated as "a when a<>0 == true"
    | a & # all other digits below
    a==s%%10
    |
    a==floor(s/10)
    |
    a==floor(s/100)
    ] # R does not require a print command, so this as-is will display the corresponding values
```

Comment: Why no whitespace?

Comment: @duci9y Because none is necessary. I'll format to be more readable and add that as well, just for good measure.

Comment: Doesn't work with `0`.

Comment: @duci9y It does not fail. I made one small change from the original post (+2 chars), as the original post DID fail on `0`. Did you try with this most recent version? I'm using R 3.0.1.

Comment: @duci9y To be clear, I meant did you use this on the most recent version *of my code*. My version of R should be close enough to the most recent version to not matter. However, I did not test at all on any 2.* versions.

Comment: Sorry, I tested this code while you were making your edit. It works. Could you edit it a little bit so it allows me to upvote?

Comment: @duci9y Updated.

Answer (score 3):

**Javascript 116**

```
   a = 0
        for(i=-100;101>i;i++){
        m=Math
        f=m.floor
        j = m.abs(i)
        if((j>10&&f(j/10)==a)||j-f(j/10)*10==a||j/100==a){

             console.log(i)

        }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

## Prolog: 75

```
f(D) :-
  between(-100,100,N) ,
  number_chars(N,Ds) ,
  member(D,Ds) ,
  writeln(N) ,
  fail
  .
```

Comment: How do you call this? I saved it in a `test.pl` file, started `swipl`, entered `consult('test')` and then entered `f(9)`. But it only returned `false`.

Answer (score 3):

### C answer in 98 characters

This is one of the sexiest things I've ever coded

```
main()
{
    int t=getchar()-48,i=100,j=-i;
    while ((i=t-i%10?i/10:!printf("%d\n",j)) || (i=++j<0?-j:j)<101  );
}
```

The older version, with 104 non-whitespace chars:

```
int main()
{
    int t=getchar()-48,i,j=-101;
    while(++j<101)
    {
        i=j<0?-j:j;
        while(i = t-i%10?i/10:!printf("%d\n",j));
    }
}
```

"Works for me" using GCC and CLANG.

Comment: Awesome! Welcome to Code Golf.

Answer (score 3):

## GW Basic: 107 characters excluding whitespace

```
1 input n
2 for i=-100 to 100
3 j=abs(i):a=j mod 10
4 if a=n then 8
5 b=j\10
6 if (b=n) and b then 8
7 if (b<10) or n<>1 then 9
8 print i
9 next
```

Using single digits for the line numbers helps and stripping the whitespace means there isn't really a need for having multiple statements on a line more than once to keep numbers reaching 10.

Answer (score 2):

## GNU coreutils (44)

```
read N
seq -100 100 | grep $N | tr '\n' ' '
echo
```

where `tr` is used to convert newlines to spaces, and `echo` provides one final newline.

```
$ bash ./script
9
-99 -98 -97 -96 -95 -94 -93 -92 -91 -90 -89 -79 -69 -59 -49 -39 -29 -19 -9 9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

Comment: This isn't much different from an [existing answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23025/8560).

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript - 108

Not sure if existing javascript answer will be taken into consideration because it uses regex, so I created one without it:

```
for(x=+prompt(i=-100);i<101;i++)if((j=i<0?-i:i)&&j%10==x||((j/100==x||(0|j/10)==x)&&x)||j==x)console.log(i)
```

Can also be shortened to 101 if x variable is put directly, like:

```
for(x=5,i=-100;i<101;i++)if((j=i<0?-i:i)&&j%10==x||((j/100==x||(0|j/10)==x)&&x)||j==x)console.log(i)
```

It basically checks if absolute values of div or mod operations are equal to the digit (which also works for 100).

Comment: If `x=1`, this fails to print `-100` or `100`.

Comment: Should be fixed now

Comment: `1` works nicely, but now `0` prints `1`, `2`, `3`... Sorry to be a troublemaker here.

Comment: Well if you put x=0; it works ok, the problem was that `prompt()` returns string, so I added *1 and it hopefully should be ok now. THank you for your suggestions

Comment: parseInt implies string too.

Comment: I was referring to first assignment, `x=prompt()*1` which before was `x=prompt()`. In the first case `if (x)` returns `false`, while in the seconds `if (x)` returns true, for the same value written in prompt window (0), because in first case it is actually `0` which evaluates to `false`, while in second case it is `"0"` which evaluates to true. This is important for the last part of `if`, which in my javascript is `&&x`, which depends on `prompt()` being integer.

Comment: `parseInt(j/10)` can be replaced with `(0|j/10)` which is both shorter and avoids the implicit strings. The (unavoidable) string-to-number conversion in `prompt()*1` cannot be shortened as `+prompt()`. (Or shorter still, change the function to start `for(x=+prompt(i=-100);...`.

Comment: You can save 1 char changing `i=-100;i<101;i++)` to `i=-101;++i<101;)`

Comment: You can also save another putting `x=5` out and above `for`

Comment: And maybe -3 changing `(j=i<0?-i:i)&&j%10==x` to `(j=i<0?-i:i)%10==x`

Answer (score 2):

## J - 27 chars

All whitespace is safely removable, meaning 27 characters. Negative numbers in output will have `_` for a negative sign: this is just the way J writes its negative numbers.

```
((e. 10 #.^:_1 |)"0 # ]) & (i: 100)
```

Explained:

- `V & (i: 100)` - Bind (`&`) the set of numbers from -100 to 100 inclusive (`i:100`) as the right argument of the main verb (`V`). The single argument of the entire verb gets piped into the left side.
- `(U"0 # ])` - Use the result of the verb `U` over each number from the right argument (`"0`) to select (`#`) items from the right argument (`]`).
- `(e. 10 #.^:_1 |)` - Given the digit to test for as the left argument and the number to check as the right argument, expand in base 10 (`10 #.^:_1`) the absolute value of the number (`|`), and check if the digit is an element of that expansion (`e.`).

Usage:

```
   ((e. 10 #.^:_1 |)"0 # ]) & (i: 100) 0
_100 _90 _80 _70 _60 _50 _40 _30 _20 _10 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
   ((e. 10 #.^:_1 |)"0 # ]) & (i: 100) 5
_95 _85 _75 _65 _59 _58 _57 _56 _55 _54 _53 _52 _51 _50 _45 _35 _25 _15 _5 5 15 25 35 45 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 65 75 85 95
```

Comment: The underscore-for-negative convention in J always bothered me -- it wouldn't be so bad if it used a minus symbol in output (without messing with the format verb).

Comment: The underscore is J's unambiguous (and, I would argue, elegant and APLish) way of differentiating negative signs from the verb `-` Negate/Minus. K lets you use the negative sign "naturally" in numbers, and incidentally K came out an arcane syntactic clusterfuck. If it's really irking you, work in your choice of `;8!:1`, `'4.0'8!:2`, or `'-'I.@:=&'_'}":`, costing 7, 11, and 16 chars respectively to make the resulting program a function instead of an expression, by my count.

Comment: I know what it is, but it's a bit bothersome all the same when it comes to I/O. It'd be nicer if it produced minus signs by default when printing numbers, rather than printing underscores presumably in case someone wanted to eval the resulting string.

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy, 127

```
def x = args[0].toInteger()
for (k in -100..100)
    if (k == x)
        print " ${k}"
    else
        for (n = Math.abs(k); n > 0; n = (int) n / 10)
            if (n % 10 == x) {
                print " ${k}"
                break
            }
```

No strings (except to output the spaces between the numbers), no char arrays or other arrays, no regexes. Tested with 0. Output:

-100 -90 -80 -70 -60 -50 -40 -30 -20 -10 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100

Comment: And I discovered a new language today. :)

Answer (score 2):

**GROOVY, 71**

```
f={z->
  _=10
  (-_*_.._*_).grep {
    a=it.abs()
    b=a%_==z
    a<_?b:b||(int)(a/_)%_==z
  }
}

println f(0)
println f(9)
```

Results in

```
[-100, -90, -80, -70, -60, -50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
[-99, -98, -97, -96, -95, -94, -93, -92, -91, -90, -89, -79, -69, -59, -49, -39, -29, -19, -9, 9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <strike>86</strike> 75 (78 with necessary whitespaces)

```
f 0=[-100,-90..100]
f d=[b|b<-[-100..100],abs(b`quot`10)==d||abs(b`rem`10)==d]
```

Ungolfed:

```
f dig =
  if dig == 0
    then [-100, 90 .. 100]
    else [num | num <- [-100 .. 100], abs (num `quot` 10) == d || abs (num `rem` 10) == d]
```

Comment: If you use a two line definition with pattern matching, i.e. `a 0=[-100....` and `a d=[b|b<-....` you can get rid of the `if then else` and save a few bytes.

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript 96**

Using bitwise or:

```
b=Math.abs;
a=prompt();
for(i=-100;i<101;)
    if(!(b(i++/10)^a && b(i%10)^a)||b(i)/a==100)  console.log(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

### VBA 121

(no whitespace or `Sub` definition counted):

```
Sub t(d)
For n = -100 To 100
m = Abs(n)
o = o & IIf(d = 0, IIf(d = n Mod 10, " " & n, ""), IIf(d = n Or d = m Mod 10 Or d = Int(m / 10) Or d = Int(m / 100), " " & n, ""))
Next
MsgBox o
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this work with `0`?

Comment: @duci9y Yes. Specifically because: `IIf(d = 0, IIf(d = n Mod 10, " " & n, "")`

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 172 chars

```
def f(x,y,z):
    if x%10==y or (x>9 and x/10==y) or (x==100 and y==1):
        print z
def g(x,y):
    f(abs(x),y,x)
    if x<100:
        g(x+1,y)
def h(y):
    g(-100,y)
```

To test within Python:

```
>>> h(4)
-94
-84
-74
...
-49
-48
...
```

Answer (score 1):

## perl, 117 with non-meaningful whitespace chars removed

I think you were looking for something more like this. Reads from stdin, outputs one line per match. No regexps, arrays (or sets or hashes or anything else that is an array under the covers) or strings, implicit or otherwise, except the strings passed to print:

```
chomp($x=<>); for($y=-100;$y<101;++$y) { $a=abs $y; print "$y " if $a % 10 == $x || $a > 9 && int( $a/10 ) == $x || $a==100 && $x==1}; print "\n"
```

eg:

```
ski@anito:~$ echo 0 | perl -e 'chomp($x=<>); for($y=-100;$y<101;++$y) { $a=abs $y; print "$y " if $a % 10 == $x || $a > 9 && int( $a/10 ) == $x || $a==100 && $x==1}; print "\n"'
-100 -90 -80 -70 -60 -50 -40 -30 -20 -10 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 

ski@anito:~$ echo 1 | perl -e 'chomp($x=<>); for($y=-100;$y<101;++$y) { $a=abs $y; print "$y " if $a % 10 == $x || $a > 9 && int( $a/10 ) == $x || $a==100 && $x==1}; print "\n"'
-100 -91 -81 -71 -61 -51 -41 -31 -21 -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -1 1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91 100 

ski@anito:~$ echo 2 | perl -e 'chomp($x=<>); for($y=-100;$y<101;++$y) { $a=abs $y; print "$y " if $a % 10 == $x || $a > 9 && int( $a/10 ) == $x || $a==100 && $x==1}; print "\n"'
-92 -82 -72 -62 -52 -42 -32 -29 -28 -27 -26 -25 -24 -23 -22 -21 -20 -12 -2 2 12 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 32 42 52 62 72 82 92
```

Answer (score 1):

## F# <strike>87</strike> 92 - 7

```
let f n = {-100..100}
|>Seq.filter(fun x->abs x%10=n||abs x/10=n&&n>0)
|>Seq.iter(printf"%d ")
```

added 5 chars because 0 wasn't handled correctly. (Single digit values would all be returned.)

Answer (score 1):

This is my first time playing code golf.  This looks pretty interesting.  I can't win, but I tried and wanted to show what I could do.

**Python: 104 (89 if I can mulligan the import) - if the results must be printed exactly as shown in the example**

```
from math import *

def g(x):
    t = 10
    p = lambda i: x == i % t or i >= t and p(i / t)
    for i in range(-100, 101):
        if p(abs(i)):
            print i,
    print
# g(0)
# -100 -90 -80 -70 -60 -50 -40 -30 -20 -10 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

**Python: 71 - if the output can be done outside the function and the only restriction for the output is that no violating numbers are printed**

```
f = lambda x: [(-i, i) for i in range(101) for j in (10, 100) if i % j == x or i >= j and i / j == x]
# print f(0)
# [(0, 0), (0, 0), (-10, 10), (-20, 20), (-30, 30), (-40, 40), (-50, 50), (-60, 60), (-70, 70), (-80, 80), (-90, 90), (-100, 100), (-100, 100)]
```

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript 125 char**

Sorry for the several edits I've been having troubles doing this from my phone :)

```
function c(n,i){o=i||0;h=100;j=o-h;f=Math.abs(j);m=f/10|0;if((m==n&&m!=0)||n==f%10||f/h==n)console.log(j);if(o<h*2)c(n,o+1);}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Powershell - <strike>20</strike> 17 chars

To match the digit 9 (for example):

```
-100..100-match 9
```

EDIT: found I could remove brackets and one piece of whitespace.

Comment: Actually it's 16 characters, rules say whitespace doesn't count.

Answer (score 1):

## Dogelang, 42 non-whitespace characters

```
f=n->for i in(-100..101)=>if n in str i=>print i
```

Same as my Python solution, just converted to [dogelang](http://pyos.github.io/dg/).

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica - 65 chars

```
f@n_:=If[IntegerDigits@#~MemberQ~n,Print@#]&~Scan~Range[-100,100]
```

Comment: Can you point me to a webpage that explains the ~ operator?

Comment: Hi @MichaelStern, it's called infix form. Here is [Wolfram page](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions.html) explain it.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 (70)

```python
def f(i):
 n=-100
 while n<101:
  m=abs(n)
  if i in [m%10]+[m/10,m>99]*i: print n,
  n+=1
```

For `i=0` to work, the `*i` makes the `m/10` condition not be checked. When `i=1`, we get `m=100` to be accepted by adding the condition `m>99`, which evaluates to `True` which equals `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby

```
def f(n);-100.upto(100){|i|print"#{i} "if(i.abs/10==n||i.abs%10==n)};end
```

Answer (score 0):

**C#**

```
IEnumerable<int> f(int a)
{
    yield a;
    yield -a;
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        yield (i * 10) + a;
        yield (i * -10) - a
    }

    if (a != 1) yield break;
    yield 100;
    yield -100;
}
```

Comment: Because it is a [tag:code-golf], please include the character count of your code in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 91 (or possibly 90)

```
f = lambda x: filter(lambda y: x in(abs(y) % 10, abs(y)/10, abs(y)/100) if x else y%10 < 1, xrange(-100,101))
```

Examples:

```
>>> f(0)
[-100, -90, -80, -70, -60, -50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
>>> f(1)
[-100, -91, -81, -71, -61, -51, -41, -31, -21, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -1, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 100]
```

If lists do not count as arrays, we can get rid of the `x` in `xrange` and maintain correctness for a total score of **90**. If we remove unnecessary whitespace, the *total* length becomes 97 (or 96).

Answer (score 0):

**C++ - 235 char**

First post on here, gave it a shot

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    std::string is = std::to_string(input);
    for(int i = -100; i < 101; i++){
        std::string os = std::to_string(i);
        if(os.find(is) != std::string::npos)
            cout << os << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!  Seems you might have missed the rule "You cannot use strings or char arrays." :)

Comment: Ah I missed that 's' on Strings, thought it meant no string arrays, oh well.

Answer (score 0):

## Fortran 95: 90 characters

```
n=9
do i=0,9
print*,10*i+n,-10*i-n
if(n>0)print*,10*n+i,-10*n-i
enddo
if(n<2)print*,100,-100
end
```

Note: it sometimes outputs a same number twice, but the rules say nothing about this being illegal

Comment: I think the output is not in the right order.

Comment: but where does it say in the rules it should be ordered?

Comment: @gilberto.agostinho.f It doesn't.  In fact it doesn't even say _only_ the numbers containing that digit or how many times they can be printed.

Answer (score 0):

## LOLCODE: 364 characters (without whitespace)

```
HAI
I HAS A N ITZ 1
I HAS A VAR ITZ 0
I HAS A I
I HAS A J
IM IN YR LOOP
  UPZ VAR!!1
  I R PRODUKT OF 10 AN VAR
  I R SUM OF I AN N
  J R DIFF OF 0 AN I
  VISIBLE I
  VISIBLE J
  N BIGR THAN 0, O RLY?
    YA RLY
      I R PRODUKT OF 10 AN N
      I R SUM OF I AN VAR
      J R DIFF OF 0 AN I
      VISIBLE I
      VISIBLE J
  OIC 
  IZ VAR BIGR THAN 8?, GTFO, KTHX  
KTHX
N SMALLR THAN 2, O RLY?
  YA RLY
    VISIBLE "100"
    VISIBLE "-100"
OIC
KTHXBAI
```

Similar to my Fortran 95 code, it sometimes outputs a same number twice, but the rules say nothing about this being illegal. Numbers are NOT output in order, bu the rules also say nothing about it.

You can run this code at: http://asgaard.co.uk/misc/loljs/#

Answer (score 0):

## Scala 123 characters

This works but doesn't scale to use larger numbers.

```
def a(n:Int) {
    for (x<- -100 until 100) {
        var y=x/10
        var z=x-((x/10) * 10)           
        if (x==n||(y==n&&n>0)||z==n){println(x)}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby - 59 chars

```
n=gets.chomp;$><<(-100..100).select{|x|x.to_s.include?(n)}
```

**Ex:**

```
1.9.3p448 :046 >   n=gets;$><<(-100..100).select{|x|x.to_s.include?(n[0])}
9
[-99, -98, -97, -96, -95, -94, -93, -92, -91, -90, -89, -79, -69, -59, -49, -39, -29, -19, -9, 9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99] => #<IO:<STDOUT>> 
1.9.3p448 :047 > 
1.9.3p448 :048 >   
1.9.3p448 :049 >   n=gets;$><<(-100..100).select{|x|x.to_s.include?(n[0])}
0
[-100, -90, -80, -70, -60, -50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100] => #<IO:<STDOUT>> 
1.9.3p448 :050 > 
1.9.3p448 :051 >
```

Answer (score 0):

## R - <strike>71</strike> 69 chars

```
z = -100:100
j = abs(z)
h = function(x)
   z[j %% 10 == x | j > 9 & x == j %/% 10 %% 10 | x & j > 98 + x]

     > h(0)
     [1] -100  -90  -80  -70  -60  -50  -40  -30  -20  -10    0   10   20   30   40   50   60   70
    [19]   80   90  100
    > h(1)
     [1] -100  -91  -81  -71  -61  -51  -41  -31  -21  -19  -18  -17  -16  -15  -14  -13  -12  -11
    [19]  -10   -1    1   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   21   31   41   51   61
    [37]   71   81   91  100
    > h(2)
     [1] -92 -82 -72 -62 -52 -42 -32 -29 -28 -27 -26 -25 -24 -23 -22 -21 -20 -12  -2   2  12  20  21
    [24]  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  32  42  52  62  72  82  92
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby - 75 characters

Emphasizing clarity over cleverness:

```
def f(n)
  puts (-100..100).select {|x| x.abs % 10 == n || x.abs / 10 == n && n > 0}.join(" ")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ECMAScript 6) - 83 Characters (excluding whitespace)

```
n=prompt()
s=''
f=x=>x%10==n|(x>9?f(x/10|0):0)
for(a=-1;a++<100;)
    if(f(a))
        s+=' '+a+' -'+a
```

Inputting `0` outputs:

```
" 0 -0 10 -10 20 -20 30 -30 40 -40 50 -50 60 -60 70 -70 80 -80 90 -90 100 -100"
```

Inputting `1` outputs:

```
" 1 -1 10 -10 11 -11 12 -12 13 -13 14 -14 15 -15 16 -16 17 -17 18 -18 19 -19 21 -21 31 -31 41 -41 51 -51 61 -61 71 -71 81 -81 91 -91 100 -100"
```

Comment: You have strings in your answer plus @duci9y said in the comments of the challenge that it has to be in order.

Answer (score 0):

**haskell, ghci: 75 characters**

```
Prelude> let i='9'
Prelude> [x | x <- [-100..100], head (show x) == i || last (show x) == i]
[-99,-89,-79,-69,-59,-49,-39,-29,-19,-9,9,19,29,39,49,59,69,79,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99]
```

It's a basic list comprehension that gets the range -100 to 100, then ( not sure if this was against the rules ) turns x into a char list and grabs the head and tail and compares it to i, which is the input, this acts as a filter for the range.

Comment: Could you perhaps add an in-answer explanation? This way, haskell ignorant people can know what you are doing.

Comment: @Quincunx I added an explanation, I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 46

```
g(x)=filter((y)->x in digits(abs(y)),-100:100)
julia> g(9)'
1x38 Array{Int64,2}:
-99  -98  -97  -96  -95  -94  -93  …  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
```

Or 54 if I'm not allowed to return an array, seems like a silly restriction.

```
g(x)=(for y=-100:100;x in digits(abs(y))&&println(y);end)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 123

```
N(int n){for(int i=-100;i<101;i++){int x=Math.abs(i);if(x%10==n||x>9&&x/10%10==n||x>99&&x/100%10==n)System.out.print(i+" ");}}
```

Since the question only asks for a function and not a whole program this should do.
Full program:

```
class N
{
    N(int n)
    {
        for(int i=-100;i<101;i++)
        {
            int x=Math.abs(i);
            if( x % 10 == n || x > 9 && x / 10 % 10 == n || x > 99 && x / 100 % 10 == n )
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
        N n = new N(Integer.parseInt(a[0]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, <strike>155</strike> 124

That is, with only non-essential whitespace removed, everything else felt like cheating. The other Haskell answer broke both rules, so I decided to roll my own solution!

You didn't specify the order of the output, so I didn't to it in ascending order. I basically jumped to the relevant points on the number line, added either 1 or 10 ten times and printed each number.

```hs
t=(+10)
p=print
g x n f
 |n<10=p x>>p(-x)>>g(f x)(n+1)f
 |True=return()
f 0=g(-100)0 t>>p 0
f n=g(-10*n-9)0(+1)>>g(-90-n)0 t
```

Call like this:

```hs
λ> f 4
-49
49
-48
48
-47
47
-46
46
-45
45
-44
44
-43
43
-42
42
-41
41
-40
40
-94
94
-84
84
-74
74
-64
64
-54
54
-44
44
-34
34
-24
24
-14
14
-4
4
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript

```
function a(b){for(i=-100;i<=100;i++){if((i+'').indexOf(b)>-1){console.log(i)}}}
```

Usage:

```
> a(3)
-93
-83
-73
-63
-53
-43
-39
-38
-37
-36
-35
-34
-33
-32
-31
-30
-23
-13
-3
3
13
23
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
43
53
63
73
83
93
```

Answer (score 0):

**C, 99 (or 46)**

```
main(i,j){for(j=getchar()-48,i=101;i;)if(--i%10==j||i/10==j||(j<i&&i/10==j))printf("%d %d ",i,-i);}
```

results (0 twice , but that was not in the parameters):

```
100 -100 90 -90 80 -80 70 -70 60 -60 50 -50 40 -40 30 -30 20 -20 10 -10 0 0
```

but the question says all the numbers... not *only* the numbers, so you can just print all of them

```
main(i){for(i=101;i--;)printf("%d %d ",i,-i);}
```

results:

```
100 -100 99 -99 98 -98 97 -97 96 -96 95 -95 94 -94 93 -93 92 -92 91 -91 90 -90 89 -89 88 -88 87 -87 86 -86 85 -85 84 -84 83 -83 82 -82 81 -81 80 -80 79 -79 78 -78 77 -77 76 -76 75 -75 74 -74 73 -73 72 -72 71 -71 70 -70 69 -69 68 -68 67 -67 66 -66 65 -65 64 -64 63 -63 62 -62 61 -61 60 -60 59 -59 58 -58 57 -57 56 -56 55 -55 54 -54 53 -53 52 -52 51 -51 50 -50 49 -49 48 -48 47 -47 46 -46 45 -45 44 -44 43 -43 42 -42 41 -41 40 -40 39 -39 38 -38 37 -37 36 -36 35 -35 34 -34 33 -33 32 -32 31 -31 30 -30 29 -29 28 -28 27 -27 26 -26 25 -25 24 -24 23 -23 22 -22 21 -21 20 -20 19 -19 18 -18 17 -17 16 -16 15 -15 14 -14 13 -13 12 -12 11 -11 10 -10 9 -9 8 -8 7 -7 6 -6 5 -5 4 -4 3 -3 2 -2 1 -1 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python2 - 54 chars**

```python
def f(s):
    for i in range(-100, 100):
        if str(s) in str(i):
            print i,
```

Example:

```python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 11 2014, 04:42:00) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def f(s):
...     for i in range(-100, 100):
...         if str(s) in str(i):
...             print i,
... 
>>> f(0)
-100 -90 -80 -70 -60 -50 -40 -30 -20 -10 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
```

After removing all white spaces, we end up with these 54 chars:

```
deff(s):foriinrange(-100,100):ifstr(s)instr(i):printi,
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala (97)

```
def a(b:Int)=for(n←-100 to 100){val m=n.abs;if(b>0&&(m/100==b||m/10==b)||m-m/10*10==b)println(n)}
```

### Ungolfed

```
def a(b:Int)=
    for(n <- -100 to 100){
        val m=n.abs;
        if((b > 0 && (m/100==b || m/10==b)) || m-((m / 10) * 10) == b) {
            println(n)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 112 Chars

```
Sub a(n)
    For i = -100 To 100
        j = Abs(i)
        s = IIf(n * (n = j Mod 10 Or n = Int(j / 10) Or n = Int(j / 100)) Or n = i Mod 10, s & " " & i, s)
    Next
    Debug.? s
End Sub
```

Traditional PPCG Format, 132 Bytes

```
Sub a(n):For i=-100To 100:j=Abs(i):s=IIf(n*(n=j Mod 10 Or n=Int(j/10)Or n=Int(j/100))Or n=i Mod 10,s &" "&i,s):Next:Debug.?s:End Sub
```

note: +5 for `:` newlines in PPCG format

### Old Version, 99 Chars (Non-Competing)

Breaks rule against using strings

```
Sub a(n$)
    For i = -100 To 100
        j = Abs(i)
        s = IIf(n * (n = j Mod 10 Or n = Left(j, 1)) Or n = i Mod 10, s & " " & i, s)
    Next
    Debug.?s
End Sub
```

Traditional PPCG Format, 118 Bytes

```
Sub a(n$):For i=-100To 100:j=Abs(i):s=IIf(n*(n=j Mod 10 Or n=Left(j,1))Or n=i Mod 10,s &" "&i,s):Next:Debug.?s:End Sub
```

note: again, +5 for `:` newlines in PPCG format

### Usage

In the VBE Immediates Window

```
  For i = 0 To 9: Print i & ":": a (i): Next
0:
 -100 -90 -80 -70 -60 -50 -40 -30 -20 -10 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
1:
 -100 -91 -81 -71 -61 -51 -41 -31 -21 -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -1 1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91 100
2:
 -92 -82 -72 -62 -52 -42 -32 -29 -28 -27 -26 -25 -24 -23 -22 -21 -20 -12 -2 2 12 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 32 42 52 62 72 82 92
3:
 -93 -83 -73 -63 -53 -43 -39 -38 -37 -36 -35 -34 -33 -32 -31 -30 -23 -13 -3 3 13 23 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 43 53 63 73 83 93
4:
 -94 -84 -74 -64 -54 -49 -48 -47 -46 -45 -44 -43 -42 -41 -40 -34 -24 -14 -4 4 14 24 34 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 54 64 74 84 94
5:
 -95 -85 -75 -65 -59 -58 -57 -56 -55 -54 -53 -52 -51 -50 -45 -35 -25 -15 -5 5 15 25 35 45 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 65 75 85 95
6:
 -96 -86 -76 -69 -68 -67 -66 -65 -64 -63 -62 -61 -60 -56 -46 -36 -26 -16 -6 6 16 26 36 46 56 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 76 86 96
7:
 -97 -87 -79 -78 -77 -76 -75 -74 -73 -72 -71 -70 -67 -57 -47 -37 -27 -17 -7 7 17 27 37 47 57 67 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 87 97
8:
 -98 -89 -88 -87 -86 -85 -84 -83 -82 -81 -80 -78 -68 -58 -48 -38 -28 -18 -8 8 18 28 38 48 58 68 78 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 98
9:
 -99 -98 -97 -96 -95 -94 -93 -92 -91 -90 -89 -79 -69 -59 -49 -39 -29 -19 -9 9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

Answer (score -1):

OOps. Fails the 0 test

## Python 160-70= 90

```
n = int(raw_input())
for x in xrange(-100,101):
    num = abs(x)
    while num:
        if n == num%10:
            print x
            break
        num /= 10
```

this is the old **wrong** code (see comments):

## Python 141 - 0 = 141

```
import re;n=raw_input('>');print "\n".join([str(j) for j in filter(lambda x:re.compile("-?.*"+str(n)+".*").match(str(x)),xrange(-100,101))])
```

Comment: You cannot use strings!

Comment: Besides the fact that you're using strings, why use REs? You could do this without them: `n=raw_input(); print " ".join(filter(lambda x: n in x, map(str, range(-100, 101))))`

Comment: @Oberon, you can do it also without `lambda` and `map`: `s=input();print" ".join([\`i\`for i in range(-100,101)if\`s\`in\`i\`])`.

Comment: @manatwork, your code gives me a SyntaxError.

Comment: Interesting. @Oberon, could you tell us your interpreter's version? http://pastebin.com/KpsyAsJw

Comment: @manatwork, it was me. I used the wrong encoding.

Comment: I just corrected it. No strings and clearer.

Comment: Doesn't work with `0`.

Answer (score -1):

## Java

```
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
    for(int i=-99;i<=99;i++)
    {
          int a,b;
          a=i/10;
          b=i%10;
          if(a==9||b==9||a==-9||b==-9){
              System.out.println(i);
                        }
    }
                                     }
```

JAVA:: O/P
-99
-98
-97
-96
-95
-94
-93
-92
-91
-90
-89
-79
-69
-59
-49
-39
-29
-19
-9
9
19
29
39
49
59
69
79
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99

Comment: Can you include the language name and the character count please?